# Django - Update User instance by form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

## Befor all :

**Djano VERSION = 1.8**, and  it's obligatory that I use this version

## Question

I do not know why I cannot update the User instance by a form.

I mean by updating: changing the value in the database and in the request

The User model is not created by me but I use django.contrib.auth.models.User

## Code

This is my code

app/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ModificationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email']
```

app/views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render
from app.forms import ModificationForm


@login_required
def profil(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
    form = ModificationForm(data=request.POST, instance=request.user)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
    else:
        form = ModificationForm()

    return render(request, "profil.html", {'form':form})
```

profile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Profil</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Profil</h1>
        <a href='/deconnexion'> Logout </a>
        <form method="post" action=".">
           {% csrf_token %}
           {{ form.as_p }}
           <input type="submit" value="Enregistrer" />
       </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your posting to the wrong link!
If you do not know it, just leave the action **empty** in the html insted of  `action="."` !